# Non-static method 'getApplicationContext()' cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, android-room

I followed instructions in [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room#java) to setup and create Room database, DAO and Data Entity.
Everything is fine until i got an error when trying to create an instance of the database:
`Non-static method 'getApplicationContext()' cannot be referenced from a static context`

Here is my code:

```java
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo;
import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Database;
import androidx.room.Delete;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.Fts4;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;
import androidx.room.Query;
import androidx.room.Room;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;
import androidx.room.Update;

import java.util.List;

@Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 0)
abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract UserDAO userDao();
}

@Fts4
@Entity(tableName = "users")
class User {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "rowid")
    public int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    public String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "age")
    public int age;
}

@Dao
interface UserDAO {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    void insertUser(User... user);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM users")
    List<User> findAllUser();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE rowid = :rId")
    User findUserById(int rId);

    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    void updateUser(User user);

    @Delete
    void deleteUser(User user);
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(Context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "main").build(); // I got error in this line
        UserDAO userDAO = db.userDao();
        List<User> users = userDAO.findAllUser();
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Or someone who has had this error since the first time using this Room library can give me a solution? Or simply just create an instance for Context ?

Comment: maybe you could an activity (which is a context) instead of having the static java main

Comment: @Blackbelt 
But what if I just want to check the structure of the database but don't want to use the activity? Or i must to use at least 1 activity ?

Comment: You must.  Your `main` method won't be called if this is an Android app; see https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/intro-activities.  First paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You MUST have a Context somewhere as an App will not run without an Activity and thus a Context. In which case you could have:-

```
class Main {
   static void main(String[] args, Context context) {
      AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, "main").build(); // I got error in this line
      UserDAO userDAO = db.userDao();
      List<User> users = userDAO.findAllUser();
   }
}
```

- i.e. the Context is passed to the `main` Method of the `Main` class.

An example use, from an Activity (MainActivity in this example) :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AppDatabase db;
    UserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Main.main(new String[]{}, this);
    }
}
```

However, you have further issues.

The first is the use of the `@Fts4` annotation, without consideration of what FTS is and how to use it, will result in results that you will not expect.

- For testing the @Fts4 annotation was commented out

The next issue is that Room, by default, will not allow access to the database on the main thread. As such the attempt to use the `findAllUser` method would fail

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
```

So `.allowMainThreadQueries` was added so the `main` method becomes:-

```
class Main {
   static void main(String[] args, Context context) {
      AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, "main")
              .allowMainThreadQueries() // ADDED to allow running on the main thread
              .build(); // I got error in this line
      UserDAO userDAO = db.userDao();
      List<User> users = userDAO.findAllUser();
   }
}
```

- Note that the last line if the `@Fts4` annotation is included will not compile.

It will then be seen that a database version number of 0 cannot be used, this was changed to 1.

Now the App.

**However**

It is suggested that you instead consider using a Singleton. That is a single databasebuild is undertaken when subsequent requests for an AppDatabase return the existing/built AppDatabase.

e.g. using:-

```
@Database(entities = {User.class}, version = /* CANNOT BE 0*/ 1)
abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
   public abstract UserDAO userDao();

   private static volatile AppDatabase instance;
   static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
      if (instance==null) {
         instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,AppDatabase.class,"other")
                 .allowMainThreadQueries()
                 .build();
      }
      return instance;
   }
   static AppDatabase  getInstance() throws Exception {
      if (instance!=null) return instance;
      throw new Exception("AppDatabase - Attempt to get an instance without a Context when the instance has not been instantiated");
   }
}
```

- Note that the second, parameterless version of getInstance, is an example of how you could get the AppDatabase instance where you cannot/will not have the Context. As can be seen `instance` **MUST** have been previously instantiated.
- Obviously handling the case when `instance` has not been instantiated could be altered to suit.
- Note that the database name has been changed and thus both the original and the suggested can be used together.

With the above and changing `MainActivity` to be:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AppDatabase db;
    UserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            db = AppDatabase.getInstance();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Main.main(new String[]{}, this);

        db = AppDatabase.getInstance(this);
        userDAO = db.userDao();
        userDAO.findAllUser();
    }
}
```

The the it all runs OK (Note that the `@Fts4` annotation is still commmented out).

Using App Inspection then the following is displayed:-

[image]

As can be seen the database accessed via the `main` method, isn't available as App Inspection believe it to be closed.

The `other` database is available and includes the table according to the `User` class, with the three columns as per the Room annotations and there is no issue with the @Dao annotated methods.

If `@Fts4` is un-commented. Then compiling fails with

```
The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [id] in a.a.so75385670.User even though they are annotated as non-null or primitive. Columns returned by the query: [name,age]
```

- for both `findAllUser` and `findUserById`

So Commenting out both of these and the use corrects the compile. However the database will not then be accessed. So to force access to the database instead of invoking the finAllUser method the use of `db.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();` is used and the App run. Now AppInspection (at least for the `other` database) shows a remarkable difference:-

[image]

If you intend to use FTS then you need to ascertain how to use it and certainly correct.

In regard to your `findAllUser` and `findUserById` you can change them to
be:-

```
@Query("SELECT *, rowid FROM users")
List<User> findAllUser();

@Query("SELECT *,rowid FROM users WHERE rowid = :rId")
User findUserById(int rId);
```

- i.e. getting the normally hidden (and thus not extracted by *) rowid column